# How to split a url from last slash using regex?

Tags: regex

I want to split a url into two from last `/`, for example:

`http://github.com/members` into `http://github.com` and `members`

So far I have tried https://regex101.com/r/SiVvRA/1, which just gives me the second part. Any pointers?

Comment: hey, thanks for the downvote!

Comment: Unfortunately I broke it with the upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending what language you are using, you may simply use a built in `split` method; But for a regex solution, you can match the string into two groups and extract them accordingly:

```
^(.*)/([^/]*)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/SiVvRA/2

Answer (score 3):

To split on the last slash, split on *slash not followed by another slash*, using this regex:

```
/(?!.*/)
```

See [live demo of this regex matching the last slash](http://rubular.com/r/vlcvBJSuBc)

See [live demo of this regex being used in this Java to split](https://ideone.com/XQLyVv):

```
String url = "http://github.com/members";
String[] parts = url.split("/(?!.*/)");
Arrays.stream(parts).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
http://github.com
members
```

Comment: @Vishal it could be because you don’t think that the slashes in my regex are part of the regex. If regex101 uses slash to delimit the regex (like JavaScript) then you’ll have to escape the slashes - see link in my answer showing both escaping and that the regex works correctly

Comment: @Vishal for clarity, I’ve added some java code and a link where you can see the java code working as desired.